# Is copying primitive types atomic on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, arm, atomic

I am about to implement custom getters and setters for atomic properties in Objective-C on iOS. I am not sure if copying primitives types (like `char, short, int, long, long long, float, double, long double`) is guaranteed to be atomic on iOS platform and ARM architecture.

Is copying primitive values when assigning to a variable or returning from a method atomic operation?

Comment: According to the answer by @auselen you can get first half of an old value and second half of a new value in case of 64-bit types on 32-bit ARM platform. Sorry about the spelling mistake.

Comment: *Long long* and *double* will be atomic depending on the CPU type.  For instance the Cortex-A programmers manual Section 16.2 on *Alignment* and 22.4 *Exclusive Access*.  You also have cache coherency issues.  The answer is both yes and no depending on the alignment, MMU properties, and physical bus to the device.  I am sure primitives for atomics already exist on [your platform](http://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html).  You should use the supplied primitives instead of writing your own; especially if you don't control the OS.  Load or store are different than *load, modify*, and *store*.

Comment: If you rely on atomicity you likely have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

If iOS device running on an 32-bit ARM architecture then any 64-bit access is *not atomic*.

This makes `long long` and `double` access not atomic on 32-bit ARM devices.

Afaik Objective-C does not support the `long double` type.

You can compare Linux's atomic implementation for ARM architectures to get some more information and ideas:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h